# Stack Overflow and Segmentation Fault in For Loop

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

Here my code and I don't know what's the reason of this error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> readFile(char* fileName)
{
    vector < vector < int > > info;
    ifstream file(fileName);
    string line;
    while ( getline(file, line) )
    {
        vector < int > data;
        double value;
        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> value)
        {
            data.push_back(value);
        }
        info.push_back(data);
    }
    return info;
}

void print2DVector(vector <vector <int> > input)
{
    for ( vector < vector < int > > :: size_type i = 0, size = input.size(); i < size; ++i)
    {
        for ( vector < int > :: size_type j = 0, length = input[i].size(); j < length; ++j)
        {
            cout << input[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

vector <vector <int> > inverseVector(vector <vector <int> > input)
{
    int* arr;
    arr = new int[input[0].size()];
    vector <int>  data;
    vector <vector <int> > output;
    for ( vector < vector < int > > :: size_type i = 0, size = input.size(); i < size; ++i)
    {
        for ( vector < int > :: size_type j = 0, length = input[i].size(); j < length; ++j)
        {
            arr[input[i][j]] = j;
        }
        for ( vector < int > :: size_type j = 0, length = input[i].size(); j < length; ++j)
        {
            data.push_back(arr[j]);
        }

        output.push_back(data);
        data.clear();
    }

    return output;
}

vector<vector <int>> initializeEmptyHospitals(int quota, int count)
{
    vector<vector <int>> output;
    vector<int> data;
    for(int j=0; j<quota;j++)
        data.push_back(-1);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        output.push_back(data);

    data.clear();
    return output;
}

bool isEmpty(vector <int> hospital)
{
    for(int i=0;i<hospital.size();i++)
        if(hospital[i]==-1)
            return true;

    return false;
}

void reArrangeVector(vector <int> &hospital)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < hospital.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < hospital.size()- i; j++)
        {
            if(hospital[j]>=0 && hospital[j+1]>=0)
            if(hospital[j] > hospital[j+1])
            {
                temp = hospital[j+1];
                hospital[j+1] = hospital[j];
                hospital[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void assignResident( vector <int> residentChoices ,vector < vector <int> > &hospitalsWithQuotas, int residentNumber, vector < vector <int> > inverseHospitals)
{
    for(int i=0;i<residentChoices.size();i++)
    {
        if(isEmpty(hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]]))
        {
            for(int j=0; j<hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]].size(); j++)
                if(hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]][j] == -1)
                {
                    hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]][j]=residentNumber;
                    reArrangeVector(hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]]);
                    return;
                }   
        }
        else
        {
            for(int k=0; k<hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]].size(); k++)
            {
                if(inverseHospitals[residentChoices[i]][residentNumber] < hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]][0])
                {
                    int temp = hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]][0];
                    hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]][0] = residentNumber;
                    assignResident(residentChoices, hospitalsWithQuotas, temp, inverseHospitals);
                    reArrangeVector(hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]]);
                    return;
                }
                //if(k==hospitalsWithQuotas[residentChoices[i]].size()-1)
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector < vector <int> > hospitalChoices,residentChoices,inverseHospitals,hospitalsWithQuotas;
    int quota = 3;
    hospitalChoices = readFile("data1_h1.txt");
    residentChoices = readFile("data1_r1.txt");
    hospitalsWithQuotas = initializeEmptyHospitals(quota, hospitalChoices.size());  
    inverseHospitals = inverseVector(hospitalChoices);

    for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
        assignResident(residentChoices[i],hospitalsWithQuotas,i,inverseHospitals);

    print2DVector(hospitalsWithQuotas);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In the following for loop when I write i<12 it works but for i<15 it throws a stack overflow exception.

```
for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
    assignResident(residentChoices[i],hospitalsWithQuotas,i,inverseHospitals);
```

Whole error text is in VS2012:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00CB33D9 in BLG372E HW1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00E72F50).
```

Comment: can you please paste only the relevant part of your code?

Comment: @Hasan : no, you didn't. Do you know what indentation means ? Also, you should learn how to format code on Stack Overflow. I fixed it for you. Next time, do it yourself.

Comment: actually I don't know where is the error because of that I put here all code, all these functions are related with each other. When I try to assign a resident to a hospital it works fine but with a for loop like above it doesn't work.

Comment: @Synxis thank you I will learn it, sorry for that.

Comment: Some of your functions are recursive. It seems you have an infinite recursion (which is the main cause of stack overflows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the errors in your program:

1. In readFile function, value is uninitialized and you're comparing it. Initialize it before comparing.
2. In readFile function, you're using vector and you're pushing characters in it, this is wrong.

You're getting Stackoverflow error may be because of some endless recursion.

Suggestion: please format your code before posting it to any forum, it becomes easy for others to debug it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right it has a endless recursion and I'm trying to fix it!